# To create a Function for graph of selected area from dropdown in Google Earth Engine UI

Tags: google-earth-engine, javascript, google-earth-engine-javascript-api, function

I want to develop a UI for my study purpose of JRC datasets available on the Google earth engine.  Connecting it with the dropdown list of my state and district function. Already a zoom of the district is working, however, I want to plot the graph of the selected district instead of ROI giving on the GEE. Here is my code:

```
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// DATA PRE PROCESSING

// EXTRACT STATE NAMES TO A VARIABLE
var stateNames = dist.aggregate_array('ST_NM').distinct().sort();
var distName = dist.aggregate_array('DISTRICT').sort();

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

//Set up a satellite background
Map.setOptions('Satellite');

//Center the map to India
Map.setCenter(78.9629, 20.5937, 5);

//Change style of cursor to 'crosshair'
Map.style().set('cursor', 'crosshair');

// SELECT A STATE FROM DROP DOWN SELECT WIDGET
var StateSelect = ui.Select({
  items: stateNames.getInfo(),
  placeholder: ('Select a State'),
  style: {width: '180px'},
  onChange: function getState(key) {
    print(key);
    var selectedpolys = dist.filterMetadata('ST_NM','equals',key);
    var selectedDistNames = selectedpolys.aggregate_array('DISTRICT').sort();
    print(selectedDistNames);
    
    // PASS THE COUNTY NAMES TO THE ITEMS FOR THE NEXT DROP DOWN LIST
    selectedDistNames.evaluate(function(values) {
    distSelect.items().reset(values);
    distSelect.setValue(values[0], false);
});
  }
});

// SELECT AREA OF INTEREST FROM DROP DOWN SELECT WIDGET
var distSelect = ui.Select({
  placeholder: ('Select a District'),
  style: {width: '180px'},
  onChange: display 
});


//This function will be called when the user changes the value in the dropdown
function display(distSelect){
  var selected = dist.filter(
    ee.Filter.eq('DISTRICT',distSelect));
  var geometry = selected.geometry();
  print(distSelect, geometry);
  Map.clear();
  Map.addLayer(geometry,{color:'grey'},distSelect);
  Map.centerObject(geometry, 10);
}
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Asset List
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

var gsw = ee.Image('JRC/GSW1_0/GlobalSurfaceWater');
var occurrence = gsw.select('occurrence');
var change = gsw.select("change_abs");
var transition = gsw.select('transition');
var roi = ee.Geometry.Polygon(
        [[[105.531921, 10.412183],
          [105.652770, 10.285193],
          [105.949401, 10.520218],
          [105.809326, 10.666006]]]);
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Constants
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

var VIS_OCCURRENCE = {
    min: 0,
    max: 100,
    palette: ['red', 'blue']
};
var VIS_CHANGE = {
    min: -50,
    max: 50,
    palette: ['red', 'black', 'limegreen']
};
var VIS_WATER_MASK = {
  palette: ['white', 'black']
};

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Helper functions
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

// Create a feature for a transition class that includes the area covered.
function createFeature(transition_class_stats) {
  transition_class_stats = ee.Dictionary(transition_class_stats);
  var class_number = transition_class_stats.get('transition_class_value');
  var result = {
      transition_class_number: class_number,
      transition_class_name: lookup_names.get(class_number),
      transition_class_palette: lookup_palette.get(class_number),
      area_m2: transition_class_stats.get('sum')
  };
  return ee.Feature(null, result);   // Creates a feature without a geometry.
}

// Create a JSON dictionary that defines piechart colors based on the
// transition class palette.
// https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/piechart
function createPieChartSliceDictionary(fc) {
  return ee.List(fc.aggregate_array("transition_class_palette"))
    .map(function(p) { return {'color': p}; }).getInfo();
}

// Convert a number to a string. Used for constructing dictionary key lists
// from computed number objects.
function numToString(num) {
  return ee.Number(num).format();
}

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Calculations
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

// Create a dictionary for looking up names of transition classes.
var lookup_names = ee.Dictionary.fromLists(
    ee.List(gsw.get('transition_class_values')).map(numToString),
    gsw.get('transition_class_names')
);
// Create a dictionary for looking up colors of transition classes.
var lookup_palette = ee.Dictionary.fromLists(
    ee.List(gsw.get('transition_class_values')).map(numToString),
    gsw.get('transition_class_palette')
);

// Create a water mask layer, and set the image mask so that non-water areas
// are transparent.
var water_mask = occurrence.gt(90).mask(1);

// Generate a histogram object and print it to the console tab.
var histogram = ui.Chart.image.histogram({
  image: change,
  region: roi,
  scale: 30,
  minBucketWidth: 10
});
histogram.setOptions({
  title: 'Histogram of surface water change intensity.'
});
print(histogram);

// Summarize transition classes in a region of interest.
var area_image_with_transition_class = ee.Image.pixelArea().addBands(transition);
var reduction_results = area_image_with_transition_class.reduceRegion({
  reducer: ee.Reducer.sum().group({
    groupField: 1,
    groupName: 'transition_class_value',
  }),
  geometry: roi,
  scale: 30,
  bestEffort: true,
});
print('reduction_results', reduction_results);

var roi_stats = ee.List(reduction_results.get('groups'));

var transition_fc = ee.FeatureCollection(roi_stats.map(createFeature));
print('transition_fc', transition_fc);

// Add a summary chart.
var transition_summary_chart = ui.Chart.feature.byFeature({
    features: transition_fc,
    xProperty: 'transition_class_name',
    yProperties: ['area_m2', 'transition_class_number']
  })
  .setChartType('PieChart')
  .setOptions({
    title: 'Summary of transition class areas',
    slices: createPieChartSliceDictionary(transition_fc),
    sliceVisibilityThreshold: 0  // Don't group small slices.
  });
print(transition_summary_chart);

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Initialize Map Location
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

// Uncomment one of the following statements to center the map on
// a particular location.
// Map.setCenter(-90.162, 29.8597, 10);   // New Orleans, USA
// Map.setCenter(-114.9774, 31.9254, 10); // Mouth of the Colorado River, Mexico
// Map.setCenter(-111.1871, 37.0963, 11); // Lake Powell, USA
// Map.setCenter(149.412, -35.0789, 11);  // Lake George, Australia
Map.setCenter(105.26, 11.2134, 9);     // Mekong River Basin, SouthEast Asia
// Map.setCenter(90.6743, 22.7382, 10);   // Meghna River, Bangladesh
// Map.setCenter(81.2714, 16.5079, 11);   // Godavari River Basin Irrigation Project, India
// Map.setCenter(14.7035, 52.0985, 12);   // River Oder, Germany & Poland
// Map.setCenter(-59.1696, -33.8111, 9);  // Buenos Aires, Argentina
// Map.setCenter(-74.4557, -8.4289, 11);  // Ucayali River, Peru

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Map Layers
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

Map.addLayer({
  eeObject: water_mask,
  visParams: VIS_WATER_MASK,
  name: '90% occurrence water mask',
  shown: false
});
Map.addLayer({
  eeObject: occurrence.updateMask(occurrence.divide(100)),
  name: "Water Occurrence (1984-2015)",
  visParams: VIS_OCCURRENCE,
  shown: false
});
Map.addLayer({
  eeObject: change,
  visParams: VIS_CHANGE,
  name: 'occurrence change intensity',
  shown: false
});
Map.addLayer({
  eeObject: transition,
  name: 'Transition classes (1984-2015)',
});

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

//App title//
var header = ui.Label('Water Monitoring Webapp (Sense for Water)', {fontSize: '25px', fontWeight: 'bold', color: '4A997E'});

//App summary//
var text = ui.Label(
  'This tool maps Water extent using JRC Global Surface Water Mapping Layers,' +
  'Use the tools below to explore changes in water extent.',
    {fontSize: '15px'});

//Create a panel to hold text//
var panel = ui.Panel({
  widgets:[header, text],//Adds header and text
  style:{width: '400px',position:'middle-right'}});
  
// Create variable for additional text and separators
//This creates another panel to house a line separator and instructions for the user
var intro = ui.Panel([
  ui.Label({
    value: '_____________________________________________________________',
    style: {fontWeight: 'bold',  color: '4A997E'},
  })]);

  
// ADD LABELS AND WIDGETS TO UI
panel.add(ui.Label('Select Area of Interest', {fontWeight: 'bold'})); 
var panel11 = ui.Panel({
  widgets: [StateSelect, distSelect],
  style: {
    backgroundColor: 'white'
  },
  layout: ui.Panel.Layout.flow('horizontal')
});
panel.add(panel11);
panel.add(intro);
ui.root.add(panel);
```

CODE: https://code.earthengine.google.co.in/db51d58190c09d4dc93272180df07097